# How can I make an Ajax call using a different set of credentials / security context

Tags: javascript, ajax, authentication, credentials, security-context

I am looking to see if it's possible to make AJAX calls to a given website using a different authentication/security/session context than the page making the AJAX call, but ideally using/accessing the same web application on the server (and authentication scheme)

e.g.: The browser requests and receives https://web.server.com/admin_page.html (which requires AUTHENTICATION) and processes the page's JavaScript, which specifies an Ajax call to something like https://web.server.com/server_info.html (which does not *require* credentials/authentication) every 30 seconds.

The page's JavaScript also automatically logs out the user after a certain time (based on the server session length). Since every call to the server that does not specifically kill the server-side session (such as the final automatic log-off call) essentially restarts the user's session timer, I'd like to be able to keep making an UNAUTHENTICATED server_info.html call every 30 seconds without affecting the user's AUTHENTICATED server-side session.

I would imagine I could do this with multiple applications on the server, which happen to access the same database and other resources, but I would greatly prefer a way to keep it all within the same application.

I guess the question is: In order to accomplish this, do I have to use separate server applications, or rather can I use the same application, and if it is possible, does it depend upon the server or application technology in use?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Just don't restart the session timer when accessing `server_info.html`. You don't have to do that on every route.

Comment: @freakish - perhaps I am making some false assumptions about how things work based on how I have had to interact with them til now - the whole session concept is handled somewhat transparently (I believe through a cookie-based session id number), each handler is mapped to a url pattern (Spring `@RequestMapping` annotation) - I do nothing manually/specifically to restart any session timer on each request, and thus I don't know how to avoid doing so. Am I making a bit more sense?

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with Spring, I'm not a Java programmer. I even googled it but it looks really confusing. :) Good luck, though!